# I want to collect data from textarea using express. What is the syntax?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I want to collect data from textarea using express nodejs from a html form. What is the syntax for that? I get 'undefined; while collecting.

for example:

to collect the input for type=text : var name = req.body.ename; is the syntax.

But how to collect 'textarea' data when user will fillup the form?

Comment: Provide some code

Comment: sorry. The post is edited.

Answer (score 0):

After the user finally fills the required field in, you can use then push the **value** of that textarea using the built-in `textareaElement.value` to the server.